# How go generate pre-rendered html files for angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm aware of Angular universal and server-side rendering, but they only seem to work for serving Angular apps, not generating the pre-rendered HTML and saving it to file.

Comment: Do you mean AOT ("ahead of time") transpiling?

Comment: @stealththeninja I may be mistaken, but I don't think that's what I want. As I understand it, AOT basically transpiles the Angular HTML and Typescript to Javascript code, which would then be executed by the browser to dynamically render the page. What I'm looking for is a way to essentially save the rendered pages to file so that when crawlers that don't support JS try to crawl my webpage, they will see "2" instead of, for example {{1 + 1}} without using server side rendering or angular universal. Because my current web host does not support Node/Express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right you want to take your client-side code and generate a copy of static HTML from it that you can deploy instead of the original application.

This is not a very common usecase, so there is (as far as I'm aware) no ready-made solution for it. [This article](https://blog.cloudboost.io/prerender-an-angular-application-with-angular-cli-and-puppeteer-25dede2f0252) describes one way you can achieve it, but I would not really recommend that you try it.

If your website is largely static anyway, you'd be better off generating it on the server side and then putting a CDN or reverse proxy in front of it that does very long-term caching of the pages.

There are also templating solutions that are specifically intended for generated static HTML; you might want to take a look at those (google "static site generator").

Comment: Thank you. In the end, I decided to switch to digital ocean as my new host.